# call blat from shell script, w8

Tags: windows, bash, shell, blat

Trying to execute blat http://www.blat.net/ from a shell script. I set the environmental `PATH` variable, and i can call `blat` from any location with the command prompt. Sending email from the command line works fine. But I'm not able to call it from within a shell script.

The (simplified) script

```
#!/bin/bash
blat
```

I get:

```
$ sh script.sh
script.sh: line 2: blat: command not found
```

I also tried by specifying the absolute path `C:/Windows/System32/blat` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this. If you will only run blat from Bash, you can
just put it in `/usr/local/bin` AKA `C:\cygwin64\usr\local\bin`.

If you need to run it from Bash and cmd/PowerShell, Windows "out of the box" has
pretty poor support for that. With Linux/Bash your PATH will usually look
something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

This is great because you have a system space, and a user space for programs.
However Windows looks like this:

```
C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows
```

As you can see by default the PATH only has system space. This is bad because it
encourages people to do dumb things like put user programs alongside protected
operating system files. What Windows needs is the equivalent of
`/usr/local/bin`, a folder on the PATH, ahead of everything where people can
dump command line programs. Until that happens you just have to add your own:

1. Move `blat.exe` to `C:\Users\<user>\Documents`
2. Add that to PATH:

   ```
   SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\<user>\Documents" /M
   ```

When you add it to Windows PATH, it automatically gets added to Bash PATH, so
the program should be available to all shells.

Comment: thank you. this was helpful. i got it working by putting blat.exe into `C:\Users\<user>\Documents` and adding that PATH to the system variables.  

But I don't quite understand why it didn't work by having blat.exe in `C:\Windows\System32` which naturally is a PATH directory.